# Laravel migration on correct DB, but data retrieve on wrong DB

Tags: laravel, homestead

I just recently put a project of mine into bitbucket as my start project. Now I cloned this project into another folder. I did the composer install command.

I created a new database for this new project and changed the variables in .env to match the new DB. When I do a 'php artisan migrate' all the tables get built in my new DB, however when I retrieve data, for example posts, it gets the posts from the other DB (used with my other project). I also checked if in the database file it was not set manually to the old DB. So I have no clue what causes this behavior.

Can anyone explain what may be the cause of this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the app clone is being served correctly from that folder? If you have no configuration info about the old database anywhere in the files of your cloned app, then it's **impossible** for it to connect to that database.

Comment: Also, as a side note, if you use `php artisan serve` to serve the cloned app, you need to rerun the command each time you make changes to any env variables, in order for them to be picked up.

Comment: check your `.env` file, and make sure you pointing to your database